# How can I install make in ubuntu without internet?

Tags: 16.04, server, xubuntu

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04. I need to install the pacakge `make` because I need to install drivers for my Ethernet device with the command "make install".  I don't have internet on this computer.  Is there any way to install this package without an internet connection?

Comment: If it's Ubuntu 16.04, why tag 14.04?   14.04 is EOL & thus off-topic on this site. @Nmath is suggested what I'd do, and use `dpkg` to install (dependencies need to be installed first; whilst `apt` will look online for what you need, since you won't have that feature available you're install line must provide the required dependencies.   Xubuntu 16.04 is EOL too, only Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, server (no desktop) and Kylin are still supported for 16.04 so you may want to check `ubuntu-support-status` to see your security status.

Comment: You probably want to install `build-essential` which includes `make` as well as other essential tools. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Do you think the duplicate will solve the problem? If not let me know and I'll retract the close vote. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It will, however, he will need build-essential, not just make.

Comment: for me on a clean install of 18.04LTS, `make` and `build-essential` were not enough. Going down a dependency hole of `gcc`, `libc-dev`, ...

Answer (score 3):

It is ***strongly recommended*** to use a package manager like `apt` or synaptic for installing software, but you can download individual packages and install them via command line.

You can search for and download packages for your distribution and system architecture on https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

The package `make` for Ubuntu 16.04 is available [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/make)

Transfer the file to the computer without internet access.

Then you can [install the .deb package from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Installing packages manually this way will not resolve dependencies, so you may be instructed to download additional packages.